# Error when following Wingtips ASP.NET Tutorial from Microsoft: SQL Network Interfaces

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2015

I was following the ASP.NET Tutorial from Microsoft. In the UI and Navigiation section, I finished everything and ran to compile when I get the following error in my browser:

`SQL Network Interfaces, error: 50 - Local Database Runtime error occurred. Cannot create an automatic instance. See the Windows Application event log for error details.`

I am running Windows 8 + Visual Studio 2015 Community Edition

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. The code calls for v11 and not v12 of the local SQL server.

Change the code in Web.config to this:

```
  <connectionStrings>
<add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\v12.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnet-WingtipToys-20131119102907.mdf;Initial Catalog=aspnet-WingtipToys-20131119102907;Integrated Security=True"
providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
<add name="WingtipToys"
connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDB)\v12.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\wingtiptoys.mdf;Integrated Security=True"
providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

Answer (score 1):

In early CTPs of Visual Studio 2015, LocalDB would automatically be installed as part of Visual Studio when you picked the default setting that included the Web Development tools.

In RTM, this was changed.

Enterprise - LocalDB is selected by default to be installed
Profesional and Community - You must select the Microsoft SQL Server Data Tools option in addition to selecting the Web Development Tools.

I apologize for this oversight. We are looking into addressing this in future updates.

If you already installed Visual Studio, just perform a Modify operation and select the Microsoft SQL Server Data Tools item.

Thanks,
Jacques

Answer (score 0):

I think the root cause of this problem is: "When you use the Typical installation of Visual Studio 2015 Professional or Visual Studio 2015 Community Edition, the LocalDB component is not installed."

Search for this text on https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3025135 and see simple work-around.  My guess is that your fix works because of a previous VS install, and will not work on clean machines.

Comment: Interesting, this was the first install of Visual Studio on this machine however. It was a relatively clean install of Windows 8, maybe a month old at most.